# WP_Query within save_post doesn't include the item that triggered the action?

Tags: wp-query, advanced-custom-fields, user-meta, save-post

I'm using Advanced Custom Field's `acf_form` function to expose a front-end form for users to post content on the website. Users will be submitting photos of redfish they have caught, and one of the datapoints is spot_count (integer).

When a new post gets published, I want to update the author's usermeta with the following:

1. total spots
2. most spots, single fish

To get this information, I've been using wp_query to iterate over their submissions and keep a running total, plus locate the highest spot count. This part works fine on a normal page.

But for some reason, when I hook into the `save_post` action in WordPress, running WP_Query doesn't include the data from the post that triggered the action. This is resulting in incorrect counts for total spots and most spots.

Is there a different hook I'm supposed to use for this? Or will this just not work because the data doesn't exist yet for WP_Query to find it?

Here's my current code:

```
/**
 * Update Angler Profile whenever they post a catch (or we manually edit one)
 */

function update_angler_profile( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

    // Query the author's redfish madness posts
    $t1stats_args = array(
    'post_type'      => 't1',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,    
    'author' => $post->post_author
        );

    // Initialize variables
    $total_spots = 0;
    $most_spots = 0;

    // Loop through posts
    $t1stats_query = new WP_Query($t1stats_args);
        if($t1stats_query->have_posts()):       

            while($t1stats_query->have_posts()):$t1stats_query->the_post();
                // Add current spot_count to overall counter
                $total_spots += get_field('spot_count');

                // If this post's spot_count is higher than the previous, set it as the new winner
                if (get_field('spot_count') > $most_spots){
                    $most_spots = get_field('spot_count');
                }

            endwhile;
        endif;
        wp_reset_postdata();        

    // Save total spots and most spots to the user's metadata
    update_user_meta($post->post_author, '_t1_most_spots', $most_spots);
    update_user_meta($post->post_author, '_t1_total_spots', $total_spots);

}

// Hook into save_post for our t1 custom post type
add_action( 'save_post_t1', 'update_angler_profile', 20, 3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to call the hook "[wp_insert_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_insert_post)". But the post-type is not what you expect - post, page oder custom post type. It's "revision".

Now you can fire a WP_Query right after the post is saved in the database.